Question on the irreducibility of induced representations of $\mathrm{GL}_n$
$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\det{det}\DeclareMathOperator\Ind{Ind}$Let $F$ be a $p$-adic local field and $\chi_i$ be unramified  characters of $F^{\times}$. For a integer $m$, define $\chi_i(m):=\chi_i(\det_{\GL_m})$.
For a partition $\tilde{n}=(n_1,\cdots,n_t)$ of $n$, consider the normalized induced representation $\pi:=\Ind_{P_{\tilde{n}}}^{\GL_n}(\chi_1(n_1)\boxtimes \cdots \boxtimes \chi_t(n_t))$. I am wondering whether $\pi$ is irreducible. If it is not, is there some restriction on $n_i$ and $\chi_i$'s so that $\pi$ should be irreducible?
Here, $|\chi_i(\omega)|=q^{s_i}$, where $-\frac{1}{2}< s_i <\frac{1}{2}$ and  $\omega$ is the uniformizer of $F^{\times}$ and $|\omega|=q^{-1}$.

According to Theorem 4.2 of Zelevinsky paper,
we have the following criterion of irreducibility:
let $\Delta_{1},\ldots,\Delta_{t}$ be segments,
then the parabolic induction
$$\pi=\mathrm{Ind}_{P_{\widetilde{n}}}^{\mathrm{GL}_{n}}\langle\Delta_{1}\rangle\boxtimes\cdots\boxtimes\langle\Delta_{t}\rangle$$
is irreducible if and only if for each $i,j$, the segments $\Delta_{i}$ and $\Delta_{j}$ are not linked.
In your case,
by Example 3.2 of Zelevinsky paper,
the character $\chi_{i}(n_{i})=\langle \Delta_{i}\rangle$,
where $$\Delta_{i}=[\rho_{i},\rho_{i}^{\prime}]=[\chi_{i}|\cdot|^{-\frac{n_{i}-1}{2}},\chi_{i}|\cdot|^{\frac{n_{i}-1}{2}}]=\left\{\rho_{i},\rho_{i}|\cdot|,\ldots,\rho_{i}|\cdot|^{n_{i}-1}\right\}$$ is a segment of length $n_{i}$.
Now if $\Delta_{i}$ and $\Delta_{j}$ are linked (we may assume that $\Delta_{i}$ precedes $\Delta_{j}$), there are two possibilities:

They are juxtaposed.
In this case $\rho_{j}=\rho_{i}^{\prime}|\cdot|$,
i.e. $\chi_{j}=\chi_{i}|\cdot|^{\frac{n_{i}+n_{j}}{2}}$.

They are linked but not juxtaposed.
In this case, there exists $k\in\{1,\ldots,n_{i}-1\}$ such that
$\rho_{j}=\rho_{i}|\cdot|^{k}$ and $\rho_{j}^{\prime}=\rho_{i}|\cdot|^{k+n_{j}-1}$ is strictly in the right of $\rho_{i}^{\prime}=\rho_{i}|\cdot|^{n_{i}-1}$.
In other words, there exists $k\in\{1,\ldots,n_{i}-1\}$ such that
$\chi_{j}=\chi_{i}|\cdot|^{\frac{n_{j}-n_{i}}{2}+k}$ and $k>n_{i}-n_{j}$.


Combining two cases, $\Delta_{i}$ and $\Delta_{j}$ are linked if and only if there exists $k\in\{1,\ldots,n_{i}\}$ such that
$\chi_{j}=\chi_{i}|\cdot|^{\frac{n_{j}-n_{i}}{2}+k}$ and $k>n_{i}-n_{j}$.
By this criterion, in your case, $\pi$ is irreducible if and only if for any $i\neq j$,
$\chi_{i}\chi_{j}^{-1}\neq |\cdot|^{k}$
for every $$k=\pm (\frac{|n_{i}-n_{j}|}{2}+1),\pm(\frac{|n_{i}-n_{j}|}{2}+2),\ldots,\pm \frac{|n_{i}+n_{j}|}{2}.$$
In particular, if all $n_{i}=1$, then the condition becomes that for any $i\neq j$ we have  $\chi_{i}\neq\chi_{j}|\cdot|^{\pm}$.

Also the claim that $\chi_i(\omega)<q^{1/2}$ prevents $\chi_j= \chi_i \cdot | \cdot |$ doesn't sound right.

@WillSawin Of course! Sorry I was in a hurry so I mistook the condition.

@GeoffRobinson Yes! Thx for your comment

@Erica, thank you for the reply! But I am wondering whether $\chi(det(GL_m))$ is cuspidal if $m>1$. Is it cuspidal?

@Andrew You remind me, it seems that we need to use The 4.2 from Induced representation paper II. I will modify the answer!

@Erica, What a great answer! Thank you very much for such a kind answer. Therefore, if $|\chi_i|=q^{s_i}$ for some $|s_i|<\frac{1}{2}$, then $\pi$ should be irreducible. May I ask you a further question? Consider the setting p-adic classical groups not general linear group, for example, let $G=Sp(2n)$, the symplectic group. Let $\tilde{\pi}$ be the induced representation from $\pi$ of the Siegel Levi subgroup $M \simeq GL_n$ of a Siegel parabolic subgroup $P$ of $Sp(2n)$ to $Sp(2n)$. Then the irreducibility of $\tilde{\pi}$ is same with that of $\pi$?

@Andrew I don't know whether there is a general criterion for the irreducibility of principal series of Sp(2n). Maybe you can look at the works of Tadic or Jantzen?

@Erica, Thank you for the comment! I am looking some papers of Tadic but it seems that there is some partial criterion on the irreducibility using Jacquet module which seems complicated. I will study this more!
